# GNURADIO: tags propagation thru delay (set_history())

Tags: stream, tags, delay, gnuradio

when putting together tags and delay, like in the below example, from [Guided Tutorials](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorial_Programming_Topics):
[image: Flow Graph]

When delay is 0, then all ok. But, when delay get bigger than 1 (e.g. 10), tags are sometimes missing in output; not propagated.

See below, example where 2 are missing: 
[image: Time signal sink showing two missing tags]
What is the reason?

Making a OOT it seems that when utilizing set_history(n) with n>1, the following happens:

1) `get_tags_in_range(tags, 0, nitems_read(0), nitems_read(0) + noutput_items);` does not detect all tags;

2) `memcpy(output_items[0], input_items[0], noutput_items);` does not propagate all tags to the output (some are missing like in above example).

How to correct this and read all tags with set_history(10)? How to ensure all tags are propagated to the output?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the delay block as is, this seems to be a bug.

I verified this by having a minimal flow graph and comparing the offsets of the post-delay tags:

[image: minimal test flow graph]

```
lastoffset = 0
ok_count = 0
for tag in tb.ref_sink.tags():
    newoffset = tag.offset
    if not newoffset == lastoffset + 100:
        print "pre-delay error: this offset %d, last offset %d" % (newoffset , lastoffset)
    else:
        ok_count += 1
    lastoffset = newoffset

print "OK: %d of %d" % (ok_count , len(tb.ref_sink.tags()))
print "="*10

lastoffset = 100
ok_count = 0
for tag in tb.vector_sink.tags():
    newoffset = tag.offset
    if not newoffset == lastoffset + 100:
        print "post-delay error: this offset %d, last offset %d" % (newoffset , lastoffset)
    else:
        ok_count += 1
    lastoffset = newoffset

print "OK: %d of %d" % (ok_count , len(tb.vector_sink.tags()))
```

(full python code [here](https://gist.github.com/marcusmueller/6b6e823dcbefe0121213) )

You should open a bug report (with a link to your question) on [the GNU Radio bug tracker](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/issues); you'll need a wiki account for that. I took the liberty to open a ticket for you. Your input would be very welcome, so please do make an account and comment on [the ticket](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/issues/864).

However, a small misconception:

`memcpy` doesn't do anything with the tags – it's really just the normal memory copy operation that takes the input *items* to the output buffer. The tag handling in GNU Radio can either be done manually, or, like in the case of the delay block, automatically by using *tag propagation policies*. For more on these, see [the GNU Radio doxygen documentation](https://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/page_stream_tags.html#stream_tags_propagation). The point here is that the block defaults to a straightforward propagation that should take care of declared sample delay without any problem. So this might be an underlying problem.